# Attach a Webform to user registration form

Tags: 7, users, webforms

Is there any way to do this in Drupal 7?

I want new users send some documents via Webform on registration.

The reason is that I don't want to save these documents as an user profile field.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the [Webform Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_registration) module. It lets any webform create users upon submission. It also lets you customize the registration process by selecting which webform elements are associated with the newly created user's name, password, & email.